# clear streetview panorama? (too many active webgl contexts)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, webgl, google-street-view

I am using a google streetview panorama, in which I slowly pan automatically. Additionally I am updating the location every 30 sec and replace the current panorama with a new one.
The problem I am having with this is, that after a while, performance goes down and I get the message `"too many active webgl contexts..."`

How can I delete/release/clear the google streetview pano (and its webgl context) before making a new one?

I tried reusing the existing context by calling `new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetview')` only once (globally) and then just update this in my function. This does get rid of the error and works as long as I am not panning - but if I do, the old and new streetview panos get mixed together and flicker randomly.

Also I tried to just clear the div layer before using it anew but that does not seem to release the webgl context.

```
function renderStreeview() {
  var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('streetview'), { disableDefaultUI: true, showRoadLabels: false} );
  streetViewService.getPanorama({ location: destination, radius: 10 }, processSVData);

  function processSVData(data, status) {
    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    var panoheading = 270;
    setInterval(function(){   // pano panning animation
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: panoheading,
        pitch: 3,
        zoom: 2,
      });
      panoheading = (panoheading + 0.06); // panning speed
    }, 50);   // panning framerate (20 fps)
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```